# The Notification System of Abp is not run .What wrong with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-boilerplate, abp

Notification System used to send some message to specific users.But global event not avaible in js file.

code in js

```
        abp.event.on('abp.notifications.received', function (userNotification) {
        console.log("userNotification", userNotification);
    });
```

code in application

```
    public class NotificationTestService : AcsAppServiceBase, INotificationTestService
    {
        private INotificationPublisher _notificationPublisher;
        private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

        public NotificationTestService(INotificationPublisher notificationPublisher, IRepository<User, long> userRepository)
        {
            _notificationPublisher = notificationPublisher;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public async void NotificationTest()
        {
            string message = "Test Message";

            var currentUser = (await this.GetCurrentUserAsync()).ToUserIdentifier();

            _notificationPublisher.Publish("NotificationTest", new MessageNotificationData(message), severity: NotificationSeverity.Info, userIds: new[] { currentUser });
        }
    }
```

1. [notification data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBnKS.png)
2. [notification data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhEo8.png)

I found the notification data in database,but event is not trigger in js file .No exception throw.
Thank you for your any help.

Comment: Are you logged in as host admin user?

Comment: yes,i do. i modified the code to test again.The result is the same as before.The code is above

Comment: Change to `async Task`.

Comment: I use the signalR.it works.Thanks for the any opinion